# Unable to split a string using split() method

Tags: c#

I have a string

```
String data="CE|2014-2015|ClassA"
```

I need output like

```
string Batch="2014-2015"
string Class="ClassA"
```

How can I achieve it?? I tried a lot string,Split() function. But I did not get expected output.Please help me out
 I tried,

```
string s = "CE|2014-2015|Class1";
string[] words = s.Split('|| ');
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Your code clearly has a compilation error, you should include any compilation errors in your questions.

Comment: You presented one set of source data here, then in the comments below you presented a different set of source data that has a different delimiter. Can you clarify what you want to do and what data you want to parse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following

```
string data = "CE|2014-2015|ClassA";
string[] split = data.Split('|');
string Batch=split[1];
string Class = split[2];
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: string data="First Year Semester 1 Feedback ". How to get only Semester 1 from it??

Comment: @SemilSebastian: now the delimiter is space? Then you have a problem  because `Semester 1` contains the delimiter.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, Is there any way to get it together??(Semester 1)

Comment: @SemilSebastian: what is the rule? Why should `Semester 1` be taken even if it consists of two tokens?

Comment: @SemilSebastian : like Tim Schmelter said you require a delimiter(character that will help to you to split like `|` above), so here you've only got `spaces`. So there's the problem. You can still achieve it by spliting with space and joining required array of strings. Example `split[2] + " "+ split[3]`

Comment: @ TFrost, yes I also think the same, need to split it with space and join

Comment: @SemilSebastian : try `string sem= split[2] + " "+ split[3]`

Comment: @SemilSebastian: you haven't mentioned a single rule, but if you just want to concatenate the third and fourth token you could also use: `string.Join(" ", data.Split().Skip(2).Take(2))`

Comment: @Tim Schmelter ,@TFrost I didnt get properly :P

Comment: @SemilSebastian : `string data = First Year Semester 1 Feedback"; string[] split = data.Split(' '); string sem= split[2] + " "+ split[3];`

Answer (score 5):

This should work for you

```
string[] splitted = data.Split('|');
string Batch = splitted[1];
string Class = splitted[2];
```

Your solution is wrong because: `'|| '` is not a valid char and it won't even compile. You should split on `|` and take second and third value from splitted values

Comment: string data="First Year Semester 1 Feedback ". How to get only Semester 1 from it??